# Gmaps.js add map marker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Would someone please advise me on how to get a map marker to display using Gmaps.js? I have the map working but cannot get a marker, perhaps I need an API key? Following is the documentation:

https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/markers.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var map;
  new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    zoom: 14,
    lat: 22.018222,
    lng: -22.861022,
  });


  map.addMarker({
    lat: 22.018222,
    lng: -22.861022,
    title: "title",
    icon: 'blah',
    infoWindow: {
    content:'test'
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMarker' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues with the posted code.

1. You aren't assigning the `GMap` object to the `map` variable.  This causes the javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMarker' of undefined`
2. the string 'blah' is not a valid icon, so once you have a map, the marker doesn't appear.

If you don't need the reference to the `GMap` object you can do this:

```
new GMaps({
  div: '#map',
  zoom: 14,
  lat: 22.018222,
  lng: -22.861022,
}).addMarker({
  lat: 22.018222,
  lng: -22.861022,
  title: "title",
  // icon: 'blah',
  infoWindow: {
  content:'test'
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cjv7k5t5/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    zoom: 14,
    lat: 22.018222,
    lng: -22.861022,
  }).addMarker({
    lat: 22.018222,
    lng: -22.861022,
    title: "title",
    // icon: 'blah',
    infoWindow: {
      content: 'test'
    }
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/gmaps.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the new GMaps object to the map variable:

```
var map = new GMaps(....
```